# How to get correct json print

Tags: python, json

I am getting some `json` data to my `flask`  API like so.

```
if len(idxs) > 0:
    # loop over the indexes we are keeping
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        data = []
        info = {}
        info['label'] = LABELS[classIDs[i]]
        info['accuracy'] = confidences[i]
        info['rectangle'] = {"height":boxes[i][0],"left": boxes[i][1],"top": boxes[i][2],"width": boxes[i][3]}
        data.append(deepcopy(info))
        res = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
```

I add 1 more field to it in the server. The field `id`.

```
 for l in range(1,128):
        img = cv2.imread("image{}".format(l), cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
        # load the neural net.  Should be local to this method as its multi-threaded endpoint
        nets = load_model(CFG, Weights)
        s = do_prediction(img, nets, Lables)
        result = {}
        result['id'] = uid
        result['object'] = s
        return result
```

Output I am getting

```
Thread : ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1,  input image: inputfolder\000000563577.jpg,  output:{
  "id": "a42feb50-7df8-5fac-aa8f-0342f0d11727",
  "object": "[\n  {\n    \"label\": \"person\",\n    \"accuracy\": 0.9530006051063538,\n    \"rectangle\": {\n      \"height\": 297,\n      \"left\": 224,\n      \"t
op\": 139,\n      \"width\": 259\n    }\n  }\n]"
}
```

Desired output:-

```
{
"id": "2b7082f5-d31a-54b7-a46e-5e4889bf69bd",
"objects": [
{
"label": "person",
"accuracy": 0.8790481352806091,
"rectangle": {"height": 114, "left": 380, "top": 363, "width": 254}
},
{
"label": "person",
"accuracy": 0.8877481352806091,
"rectangle": {"height": 114, "left": 180, "top": 63, "width": 254}
}
]
```

The new lines seem to be at the right places, but I cannot get the print correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're getting a json string, in order to convert it back to a json you have to call json.loads() on it.
P.S : you didn't ask about it but in your second piece of code, you're loading model in every iteration which is not efficient at all, load it just once out of the loop.

Comment: That helped. Thanks